# QT QML text property update

Tags: c++, qt, qml, notify

I want update qml text.text property, when main function start.
If I click the button, the text value update works but in the function  `timeoutupdate`, the qml's text value wont update ??

`main.cpp`: this is the main-function when use qml_test.init where qml text property can't update the value.

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
        QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);


    qmlRegisterType<qml_test>("Test", 1, 0, "Pagetest");


    qDebug() << " main thread =" << QThread::currentThread();

    qml_test qt;
    qt.init();


    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
    }
```

`qml_test.h`: the qml_test is qmlRegisterType to show.qml use.

```
class qml_test : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_PROPERTY(QString mainvoltage READ mainvoltage WRITE setmainvoltage NOTIFY mainvoltageChanged);
    explicit qml_test(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~qml_test();

    QString mainvoltage();
    void init();

signals:
    void mainvoltageChanged();

public slots:
    void setmainvoltage(QString str);
    void update();
    void timeoutupdate();

private:
    QString m_mainvoltage;
    QTimer *tt;

};
```

`test.cpp`

```
qml_test::qml_test(QObject *parent): QObject(parent)
{

}

qml_test::~qml_test()
{
}

void qml_test::init()
{
    tt = new QTimer(this);
    connect(tt, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timeoutupdate()));
    tt->start(5000);
}

void qml_test::update()
{
   qDebug() << QThread::currentThread();
   setmainvoltage("update");
}

void qml_test::timeoutupdate()
{

    setmainvoltage("fffffff");
    //this can not use

}

QString qml_test::mainvoltage()
{
    return  m_mainvoltage;
}


void qml_test::setmainvoltage(QString str)
{

    if(m_mainvoltage == str) return;

    m_mainvoltage = str;
    emit mainvoltageChanged();
    qDebug() << QThread::currentThread();
}
```

`main.qml`

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id:root
    visible: true
    width: 1216
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Item
    {
        id: center_item
        width: 1216;height: 103
        Loader
        {
            //id:mainloader
            sourceComponent: center_item
            source:"qrc:/show.qml"
         }
    }

}
```

`show.qml`

```
Item {
    id: center_main_show
    width: 1216;height: 103

    property string name01 : "name01"


    Pagetest{
        id:pp


    }

    Image {
        id: name
        source: "qrc:/images/bottom.jpg"
    }

    Button{
        width: 100
        height: 30
        id:btnn

        text: "dddddd"
        objectName: "qml_obj_btn"
        onClicked: {
            pp.update();
        }
    }
    Item {
        id: e_method_item
        width: 76
        height: 77
        anchors.top: center_main_show
        anchors.topMargin: 70
        anchors.left: center_main_show.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 100

        Text {
            id: tt            
            anchors.top: e_method_item.top
            anchors.topMargin: 47
            anchors.left: e_method_item.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 20
            text: pp.mainvoltage
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created yourself two instances of `PageTest`, one instantiated in main.cpp, the other in QML.

You probably want to set a context property from main, exposing the `PageTest` instance from there, using the identifier 'pp':

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("pp", &qt);
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Amfasis mentioned, the `PageTest` instantiated in QML (`pp`) is not the same instance as the `qml_test` instantiated in .cpp (`qt`). So `pp` never has `init()` called. Only `qt` does. That's why the timer never triggers an update.

If you want to create the instance in .cpp, then do as @Amfasis suggests and expose `qt` to the QML code in a context property. Then you can remove the `PageTest` object.

On the other hand, if you prefer to create your object in QML, then you would need to expose your `init()` function to the QML as well, like this:

```
class qml_test : public QObject
{
    ...
    Q_INVOKABLE void init();
```

And then call it from QML like this:

```
    Pagetest{
        id:pp

        Component.onCompleted: {
            init();
        }
    }
```